# Reading linkedlists

Tags: c#, foreach

Can I read two linked-lists in one foreach?

How can I do it?

This is my code:

```
LinkedList<Double> estimatedProxiSize = new LinkedList<Double>();
LinkedList<Double> planAddedAndModifiedSize = new LinkedList<Double>();

estimatedProxiSize.AddLast(Convert.ToDouble(130));
estimatedProxiSize.AddLast(Convert.ToDouble(650));
estimatedProxiSize.AddLast(Convert.ToDouble(99));
estimatedProxiSize.AddLast(Convert.ToDouble(150));
estimatedProxiSize.AddLast(Convert.ToDouble(128));

planAddedAndModifiedSize.AddLast(Convert.ToDouble(163));
planAddedAndModifiedSize.AddLast(Convert.ToDouble(765));
planAddedAndModifiedSize.AddLast(Convert.ToDouble(141));
planAddedAndModifiedSize.AddLast(Convert.ToDouble(166));
planAddedAndModifiedSize.AddLast(Convert.ToDouble(137));

calc(listaX,listaY);

public void calc(LinkedList<Double> listaX, LinkedList<Double> listaY)
{
         //Here, I need something like:
         foreach (var itemx in listaX and var itemy)
         {
                Double xy = itemx*itemxy;
         }
}
```

Is it possible?

Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Just so I understand this correctly, you want a sum product?  Where you have 10 items in one list, and twelve in the other, then you'll result in a list of 120 items?

Comment: try for loop and use index.

Comment: @MuctadirDinar You can't access items in a linked list by index, and even if you could, you wouldn't want to, as access by index would be O(n) not O(1).

Comment: @Servy Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but isn't that precisely what [ElementAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233.aspx) does?

Comment: @tnw `LinkedList` doesn't have an `ElementAt` operator.  `IEnumerable` does, but then you're getting O(n) element access, not O(1), as I said in the second half of my comment.  It would absolutely kill your performance to do that.

Comment: @Servy I wouldn't say that you *can't* access items in a linked list by index at least

Comment: @tnw The `LinkedList` class provides no access to items by index.  To access the item at a given index, you cannot write an efficient implementation, you must iterate the sequence to that point.  That's the primary reason it excluded an implementation to begin with, and why it shouldn't be used here.

Comment: @Servy No I totally see your point there, I was just pointing out that it isn't really correct to say that you can't access items in a linked list by index. You *can*, but as you said, you just shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both `LinkedList(T)` are the same size then `Enumerable.Zip` will work.

Otherwise you can roll your own:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> Zip<T, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<T> first,
        IEnumerable<T> second,
        Func<T, T, TResult> resultSelector
    )
    {
        using(var firstEnumerator = first.GetEnumerator())
        using(var secondEnumerator = second.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while(firstEnumerator.MoveNext() && secondEnumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                yield return resultSelector(firstEnumerator.Current,
                                            secondEnumerator.Current);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
foreach(var item in listaX.Zip(listaY, (x, y) => x * y)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Zip` to combine the items from each list that are in the same position into a single object, and then iterate that resulting sequence:

```
var zipped = listaX.Zip(listaY, (x, y)=>new{x,y});

foreach(var pair in zipped)
{
    double product = pair.x * pair.y;
}
```

Or, to simplify a bit to this specific case:

```
var products = listaX.Zip(listaY, (x, y) => x * y);

foreach(double product in products)
{
    //do stuff with product
}
```

Comment: Why not returning the x*y in Zip itself?

Comment: This should be it, but I'd incorperate @Alireza's comment.

Comment: @Alireza you certainly could.  In this case I generalized the first part to separate it out from the specific logic so that it could be more easily applied to different cases, but in this specific case that would be just fine.

Comment: should I add a library to use **.ZIP** @Servy ?

Comment: @Jean It is a LINQ method, and is a part of the base language library.  You do not need to add any additional references, merely a `using` for `System.Linq`.

Comment: @Servy I have

`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Linq;`


But it show mw it: 

**Error 'System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList<double>' no contiene una definición de 'Zip' ni se encontró ningún método de extensión 'Zip' que acepte un primer argumento de tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList<double>' (¿falta una directiva de uso o una referencia de ensamblado?)**

Comment: @Jean Are you using .NET 4.0+?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft .NET Fame 3.5 SP1 @Servy u.u

Comment: `Zip` was added in version 4.0.  You can use the implementation provided in Romoku's answer if you can't upgrade; the method is simple enough to implement.

Answer (score 0):

If `estimatedProxiSize` and `planAddedAndModifiedSize` have the same number of elements you can use `IEnumrable<T>.Zip`:

```
estimatedProxiSize.Zip(planAddedAndModifiedSize,(estim,plan)=> estim * plan));
```